# Simple OK button on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have listview component in my activity and I managed to add button below it using the layout xml file of the activity. But the problem is that when in landscape the button is not visible because the listview is very long.

So is there a way to add simple OK button to close current activity but to be visible in either landscape or portrait, modes?

I know this page [listview-voggela](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listactivity) but it is kind of complex to implement, and I am not an android expert. So I am searching for simple solution. thanks

Comment: add your button as a footer to listview. or use relativ layout place your button at the bottom relative to the button place your listview above the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/okbutton"
    android:text="@string/hello" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@id/okbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't know about your place, but my button is translucent and i see list view items beneath it. Wait it must work all of it.

Comment: oops, it works fine for me.... For instance just copy paste the code and check if is it alright?

Comment: Ok, dude it worked, I have missed an attribute, android:layout_above="@id/okbutton" thanks

Comment: Nice to hear.. COol!!